# Locale to support ISO standard for decimal and thousand separator?

Tags: javascript, locale

The US locale does not respect the [ISO standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_80000-2) (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator)):

```
> number = 1234567.89
< 1234567.89
> LOCALE = 'en-US'
< "en-US"
> number.toLocaleString(LOCALE)
< "1,234,567.89"
```

The German locale does:

```
> LOCALE = 'de-DE'
> number.toLocaleString(LOCALE)
< "1.234.567,89"
```

Is there an international locale which adheres to the ISO standard?

Where can I find the list of locales supported by `toLocaleString`? ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString))

(tested in the Chrome console)

Comment: What's your definition of "an international locale"?

Comment: @grawity A locale which respects international standards regarding number formatting, without being tied to a specific language. I am not doing language-related processing, only number formatting. It does not make sense to use `de-DE`, but better `iso-ISO`, if it existed.

Comment: @grawity or seen otherwise: I need a "locale" which adheres to international standards regarding number formatting, but which does not concern itself with other localization issues. `toLocaleString` is a method for numeric values. Therefore, it needs a parameter which specifies numeric-related properties, not other language properties.

Comment: There is a proposed `en_150` but I don't think it's actually implemented in any real system yet, and it might not support this number format. Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62316/why-is-there-no-euro-english-locale

Comment: @tripleee that is an interesting take, but my question is actually not related to language properties, simply to numeric properties. I start to think that `toLocaleString` is badly defined: it is not related to locales as defined (which concern themselves with lots of language issues), but simply to number formatting (a subset of the locale issues). Why would `toLocaleString` need to get any information about "paper size" for example? The only thing it needs is a definition for the decimal / thousands separators, and eventually an specification on how to format currencies.